# Does intersect result in non-simple geometry?

Tags: arcobjects, c#

I have some features retrieved from SDE where I perform an Intersect on. Both feature-classes from which the features come from are polygon-featureclasses.

```
IFeatureCursor cur = myFeatureClass.Search(spFilter, false);
IFeature row = null;
while ((row = cur.NextFeature()) != null)
{
    ITopologicalOperator topOp = row.Shape as ITopologicalOperator;
    IArea baseGeom = (IArea)topOp.Intersect(feature.GetEsriGeometry(), row.Shape.Dimension);

    if (baseGeom is IGeometryCollection)
    {
        IPolygon4 mPoly = (IPolygon4)baseGeom;
        IGeometryCollection mGeomCol = null;
        try
        {
            // this may throw a COM-exception when the polygon is not simple (errorcode 0x80040218 = E_GEOMETRY_NOTSIMPLE)
            mGeomCol = (IGeometryCollection)mPoly.ConnectedComponentBag;
        }
        catch
        {
            if (baseGeom is IGeometryCollection) mGeomCol = (IGeometryCollection)baseGeom;
        }
    }

    // do something with our collection
}
```

As of the ESRI-docs we know that performing an Operation on `ITopologicalOperator` will always return a topological correct geometry. Therefor both the `IsKnownSimple`- and the `IsSimple`-properties for `baseGeom` are `true`.

When I call `ConnectedComponentBag` from `IPolygon4` it throws a COM-exception:

> (0x80040218) The operation cannot be performed on a non-simple geometry.

That makes me wonder how the property of a topological correct geometry may become topological incorrect. The [docs for the property](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/Arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ConnectedComponentBag_Property/002m000002mz000000/) state that it consists of the rings of the original polygon, so **where is the difference between my `baseGeom` which is topological correct and my `ConnectedComponentBag` which is not?**

Comment: I wonder if you have geometries like an U-shaped simple polygon. If you split it with a line that crosses the both arms you will get two geometries: one simple u with shortened arms and one multipolygon that consists of the two pieces which were cut off.

Comment: Only because it is a multipart-object does not mean it is not simple, or am I whrong? Also multipart-geometries can be simple as far as I know. So even IF you cut off the two ends of this u-shaped geometry they should be topological simple.

Comment: I believe you are right. What if intersection yields a linestring or a point? I am not good at topolygy but I suppose it may happen. But such geometries should be simple as well.

Comment: @user30184 This can be avoided by using the `dimension`-parameter within the call to `Intersect`. Thus it returns only polgonal-features

Comment: Have you tried using `ITopologicalOperator3.IsSimpleEx` to see what it says?